# How to create field resolver on RedwoodJS

Tags: redwoodjs

RedwoodJS automatically maps GraphQL queries resolvers to `api/src/services`. How do I create a field resolver for a given GraphQL type?

Suppose I have this schema:

```
type Person {
  name: string!
  birthDate: DateTime!
  age: Int!
}
```

But only `name` and `birthDate` are stored in the database.

Using `graphql-tools` I would write my resolvers like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: { ... },
  Mutation: { ... },
  Person: {
    age(person) {
      return new Date().getFullYear() - person.birthDate.getFullYear();
    },
  },
};
```

PS: I know the age formula is wrong.

PS2: I'm using age here for the sake of simplicity, imagine this is expensive to compute or get from database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's almost identical to the way you do it with `graphql-tools`.

You export an object with the same name as your type in your service:

```js
// services/person.js
export const Person = {
    age: (_args, { root }) {
      return new Date().getFullYear() - root.birthDate.getFullYear();
    },
}
```

As an aside, you could also export a `resolvers` in the `person.sdl.js` file (But services take precendence):

```js
// graphql/person.sdl.js

export const schema = gql`/* ... */`

export const resolvers = {
  Query: {},
  Mutation: {},
  Person: {},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I misunderstood the question, this answer just covers creating query + mutation resolvers, not a resolver for a computed field.

To create a field resolver, you'll need to decide whether you're creating a resolver for a query, or a handler for a mutation.

We can use the following schema as an example:

```js
export const schema = gql`
  type Person {
    id: String!
    name: String!
    age: Int!
  }

  type PersonInput {
    name: String
    age: Int
  }

  type Mutation {
    createPerson(input: PersonInput!): Person
  }

  type Query {
    people: [Person]
    person(id: String!): Person
  }
`
```

If the above schema is stored in a file called `persons.sdl.js`, in the `api/src/graphql` directory, you can implement the queries and mutations in a file called `persons.js` in the `api/src/services/persons` directory.

```js
// implements Mutation.createPerson(...)
export const createPerson({ input }) => {
  return db.person.create({
    data: input
  })
}

// implements Query.people
export const people = () => {
  return db.person.findMany()
}

// implements Query.person(...)
export const person = ({ id }) => {
  return db.person.findOne({
    where: { id }
  })
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about field resolvers, not query or mutation. I'll update the question, but what I mean is: imagine Person type has a field that is computed or a relation that need another query to the database

Comment: I wonder if the resolver for the `Person.age` field should be a `age` function in a `api/src/services/persons/person.js` file